# Run `whois` and `host` on all public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of a UNIX host

Tags: shell, ip-address, xargs, gnu-parallel, dig

In UNIX shell, I'd like to script getting all public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of my gateway, print it back, and then run both [`whois`](http://mdoc.su/-/whois) and [`host`](http://mdoc.su/-/host) on all found addresses.

Additionally, because my connection is load-balanced, there might be more than one public IP-address, depending on whether ICMP, UDP or TCP is used (for example, `traceroute -P UDP` and `traceroute -P ICMP` always return different results), and/or depending on the source and the destination IP address.

What's the shortest UNIX shell snippet with which I can accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

We can use [GNU Parallel](http://ports.su/sysutils/parallel) to mix-and-match several commands and options that are at stake here.

We can determine the [public IP address through DNS](//serverfault.com/questions/89114/finding-the-public-ip-address-in-a-shell-script/560059#560059) with [`dig`](http://mdoc.su/-/dig) (the DNS lookup utility from BIND), this lets us try out both UDP (with the `+notcp` option) and TCP  (`+tcp` option), leaving only ICMP behind.  However, we can try sending all these queries to multiple independent destination IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, making it more likely that the load-balancing of the connection will take place, returning more unique responses, as expected.

As the results may contain many duplicates (i.e., if IPv6 is missing or if UDP, TCP and varying the dst-addr return identical results), we'll get rid of these with [`sort`](http://mdoc.su/-/sort) and [`uniq`](http://mdoc.su/-/uniq).

It would appear that the positioning of `-4` and `-6` with [`dig`](http://mdoc.su/-/dig) might also be handled differently — if positioned right after `dig` before the `@` specifier, then it's enforced as a hard requirement; if positioned past the `@` specifier and/or at the end of the command line, it's enforced as a soft requirement (IPv4 will be used if IPv6 is missing); the snippet below uses it as a soft requirement to avoid having to implement error-handling.

## Solution

Here's the full solution:

```
parallel -k dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short \
::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp \
| sort -n | uniq \
| parallel -vk ::: "echo" "host" "whois" :::: /dev/stdin
```

Here's the same snippet as a single line:

```
parallel -k dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short ::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp | sort -n | uniq | parallel -vk ::: "echo" "host" "whois" :::: /dev/stdin
```

Here's the same snippet SO inline:

- `parallel -k dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short ::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp | sort -n | uniq | parallel -vk ::: "echo" "host" "whois" :::: /dev/stdin`

---

Note that depending on [`whois`](http://mdoc.su/-/whois) in your system, you might have to change `"whois"` to something like `"whois -a"` (for ARIN), `whois -A` (for APNIC) or `"whois -r"` (for RIPE) to make sure that the whois request for IPv6 addresses gets sent to the proper place; this is exactly why I'm using the quotation marks in the above snippet:

- `parallel -k dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short ::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp | sort -n | uniq | parallel -vk ::: "echo" "host" "whois -a" :::: /dev/stdin`

---

## Testing

Here's a demonstration of what the two [`parallel`](http://ports.su/sysutils/parallel) invocations above work to accomplish:

```
% parallel -k echo dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short \
? ::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns1.google.com -4 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns1.google.com -4 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns1.google.com -6 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns1.google.com -6 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns2.google.com -4 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns2.google.com -4 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns2.google.com -6 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns2.google.com -6 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns3.google.com -4 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns3.google.com -4 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns3.google.com -6 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns3.google.com -6 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns4.google.com -4 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns4.google.com -4 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns4.google.com -6 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns4.google.com -6 +tcp
%
% printf '"%s"\n"%s"\n"%s"\n"%s"' "127.0.0.1" "127.0.0.1" "::1" "::1" \
? | sort -n | uniq \
? | parallel -k echo ::: "echo" "host" "whois -a" :::: /dev/stdin
echo "127.0.0.1"
echo "::1"
host "127.0.0.1"
host "::1"
whois -a "127.0.0.1"
whois -a "::1"
%
```